# mysql calling system command from stored procedure not working

Tags: c#, mysql, perl

I want to launch a system command on a server using a stored procedure

**Procedure:**

```
delimiter ## 
create procedure myProc() 
BEGIN 
\! myexe; 
END ##
```

**script /bin/myexe**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

system("halt"); 
## end script
```

When I **use:** `"mysql> call myProc;"`

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

! is a mysql (client side) command. It's used to invoke a system command on the client, and never gets passed to the server.

You can't put this kind of thing in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use ! command instead of a socket.
The script myexe will print some data to printer.
Mysql connector does not support system commands, so I thought to use a stored procedure.
I connect to mysql server on a PDA using C #, and using the command system would be much faster.